# printf and long double

Tags: c, gcc, printf, long-double

I am using the latest gcc with Netbeans on Windows. Why doesn't `long double` work? Is the `printf` specifier `%lf` wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float aboat = 32000.0;
    double abet = 5.32e-5;
    long double dip = 5.32e-5;

    printf("%f can be written %e\n", aboat, aboat);
    printf("%f can be written %e\n", abet, abet);
    printf("%lf can be written %le\n", dip, dip);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
32000.000000 can be written 3.200000e+004
0.000053 can be written 5.320000e-005
-1950228512509697500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
can be written 2.725000e+002
Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/135253-printing-long-double-type-via-printf-mingw-g-3-2-3-a

Comment: obviously there is a problem with MinGW and long double

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't print correctly a long double in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to the wrong modifier, which port of gcc to Windows?  mingw uses the Microsoft C library and I seem to remember that this library has no support for 80bits long double (microsoft C compiler use 64 bits long double for various reasons).

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/135253-printing-long-double-type-via-printf-mingw-g-3-2-3-a

Answer (score 56):

Yes -- for `long double`, you need to use `%Lf` (i.e., upper-case 'L').

Answer (score 50):

From the printf manpage:

> l      (ell) A following integer
>   conversion corresponds to a long int
>   or unsigned long int argument, or a
>   following n conversion corresponds to
>   a pointer to a long int argument, or a
>   following c
>                 conversion corresponds to a wint_t argument, or a following s
>   conversion corresponds to a pointer to
>   wchar_t argument.

and

> L      A following a, A, e, E, f, F,
>   g, or G conversion corresponds to a
>   long double argument.  (C99 allows
>   %LF, but SUSv2 does not.)

So, you want `%Le` , not `%le`

Edit: Some further investigation seems to indicate that Mingw uses the MSVC/win32 runtime(for stuff like printf) - which maps long double to double. So mixing a compiler (like gcc) that provides a native long double with a runtime that does not seems to .. be a mess.

Comment: Which compiler are you using with Netbeans on Windows ?

Answer (score 32):

If you are using MinGW, the problem is that by default, MinGW uses the I/O resp. formatting functions from the Microsoft C runtime, which doesn't support 80 bit floating point numbers (`long double` == `double` in Microsoft land).

However, MinGW also comes with a set of alternative implementations that *do* properly support long doubles. To use them, prefix the function names with `__mingw_` (e.g. `__mingw_printf`). Depending on the nature of your project, you might also want to globally `#define printf __mingw_printf` or use `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` (which enables the MinGW versions of all the `printf`-family functions).

Comment: Warning: the mingw version has a performance bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970675/massive-fprintf-speed-difference-without-std-c99

Answer (score 9):

Was having this issue testing long doubles, and alas, I came across a fix! You have to compile your project with -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO:

> Jason Huntley@centurian /home/developer/dependencies/Python-2.7.3/test
>   $ gcc main.c
>
> Jason Huntley@centurian /home/developer/dependencies/Python-2.7.3/test
>   $ a.exe c=0.000000
>
> Jason Huntley@centurian /home/developer/dependencies/Python-2.7.3/test
>   $ gcc main.c -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
>
> Jason Huntley@centurian /home/developer/dependencies/Python-2.7.3/test
>   $ a.exe c=42.000000

Code:

```
Jason Huntley@centurian /home/developer/dependencies/Python-2.7.3/test
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   long double c=42;

   c/3;

   printf("c=%Lf\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C99 the length modifier for `long double` seems to be `L` and not `l`. `man fprintf` (or equivalent for windows) should tell you for your particular platform.

Comment: Too bad he is on Windows, and he probably doesn't have a manpage. Anyway, google for "man printf" or "printf manual page" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said in other answers, the correct conversion specifier is `"%Lf"`.

You might want to turn on the format warning by using `-Wformat` (or `-Wall`, which includes `-Wformat`) in the gcc invocation

```
$ gcc source.c
$ gcc -Wall source.c
source.c: In function `main`:
source.c:5: warning: format "%lf" expects type `double`, but argument 2 has type `long double`
source.c:5: warning: format "%le" expects type `double`, but argument 3 has type `long double`
$
```

Answer (score 2):

printf and scanf function in C/C++ uses Microsoft C library and this library has no support for 10 byte long double. So when you are using printf and scanf function in your C/C++ code to print a long double as output and to take some input as a long double, it will always give you wrong result.

If you want to use long double then you have to use " __mingw_printf " and " __mingw_scanf " function instead of printf and scanf. It has support for 10 byte long double.

Or you can define two macro like this : " #define printf __mingw_printf " and " #define scanf __mingw_scanf "

Use standard format for long double : %Lf