# Why is this long double not printing out correctly using printf?

Tags: c, printf, long-double

I need to do division using long double, on the order of 1/10^23, however the numbers get cut off when i check them using printf. Does anyone one know how I can see the full number? For example:

```
long double a = 1;
long double b = 3;
printf ("%Lf", a/b );
```

But I get:

```
0.333333
```

For example I would like to display the full number like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double)

Comment: You mean you want to see an infinite number of 3s ?

Comment: @cnicutar at least the 80 bits of long double, this is just an example

Comment: `.3333333...` will never show up due to the limited precision of floating-point numbers.  However, you could tell `printf` how many digits to display.

Comment: take a look at man printf, to see how specify precision.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double

Comment: Whether you'll ever get to print the precision you expect is implementation dependent. For example, in MSVC `long double` is the same as `double`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%f` format prints with 6 digits after the decimal point. You can use `%.df` to print d digits. Or better yet, use `%.dg` to make large/small values readable as well.