# Long double is printed incorrectly with iostreams on MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, iostream

Consider the code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << 4.2L;
}
```

Compiling it on [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and running results in the following output:

```
> g++ test.cc
> a.exe
-7.89773e-278
```

Is it a bug in MinGW and is there a fix or workaround?

**Update:**

There is a similar issue with `printf` described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089174/471164):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  std::printf("%Lg", 4.2L); // prints -7.89773e-278
}
```

However, the issue with `printf` can be fixed by defining `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` while this one can't, so I think it deserves a separate question.

Comment: Maybe is a bug, check the answere to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double)

Comment: That does seem to be nearly the same bug described in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double). MinGW uses the gcc compiler and Microsoft's runtime library; they have different representations for `long double`. The top-scoring answer (not the accepted answer) mentions a workaround for `printf`, using `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`; I'd be interested in seeing whether there's a similar workaround for `cout << ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've just checked and a similar issue exists with printf, so it is probably related.

Comment: Unfortunately __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO only fixes printf's output. I've updated the question.

Comment: This code works correctly in mingw-w64  4.9.2 (both 32-bit and 64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** a MinGW bug ... controversial as that statement may seem, the reality is that it is a limitation of Microsoft's C/C++ runtime library, upon which MinGW is dependent. As a developer, it is incumbent on you to understand the limitations of your tools, such as this one, and to work within those limitations.

The problem you are experiencing is due to Microsoft's lack of any distinct implementation of a `long double` data type in MSVC, and the consequent lack of effective support for that data type within the I/O subsystem provided by MSVCRT.DLL; (and, before you tell me, perhaps indignantly, that "of course MSVC supports `long double`", I know that it does *syntactically*, but *semantically* it has no distinct implementation, simply behaving by effectively ignoring the `long` qualifier, such that `long double` becomes a synonym for bare `double`).

Conversely, GCC and hence MinGW *does* have an implementation of `long double`, which is distinct from `double`; the former is an 80-bit entity, whereas the latter is 64-bit, and is an exact analogue of MSVC's 64-bit implementation of *both* data types. This is great when you need the greater precision of 80-bit floating point computation, but it can lead to problems, such as you are experiencing, when it comes to output of results; (the I/O translator is handed an 80-bit raw data representation of a `long double` data entity, where it expects 64-bit; the internal representations are incompatibly different, so garbage ensues when part of the mantissa is interpreted as exponent).

As you've noted, whereas MSVCRT.DLL supports only output of 64-bit `double` values, MinGW does offer an alternative implementation of C's `printf` style I/O, which can correctly translate the 80-bit format; however, this does not extend to supporting C++ style I/O. Thus, in C++ code, you cannot simply exploit the MinGW alternative I/O implementation, *while continuing to use C++ I/O semantics*; you have to recognize the MSVCRT.DLL limitation, and code your application accordingly. Some options you might consider include:--

1. Forego the use of the `long double` data type, and perform your computations as `double`; (this is the *only* option which is *effectively* available to users of Microsoft's compiler, because it doesn't really have a distinct `long double` data type implementation to begin with).
2. Perform the computation as `long double`, but cast the result to `double` for output.
3. Use C style I/O functions instead of the C++ I/O semantics, and enable MinGW's alternative `printf` implementation by compiling with any of `-posix`, `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, `-D_BSD_SOURCE`, `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`, or `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`, (or better, add `#define` for any of the latter four to your source, *before any* `#include`).  If preferred, you may also substitute any earlier compliance level for `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`; (however, please ignore the *incredibly bad advice*, which may be offered by some commentators, to compile with `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`; the double underscore, which introduces that macro name, marks it as "implementation reserved", and therefore not something which you, as an end user of the compiler implementation, should be referring to directly).
4. Use C's `snprintf` function to convert `long double` data to a C string representation, then use C++ semantics to output that instead of leaving C++ to translate the raw form of the `long double` entity directly. (IIRC, Microsoft don't provide `snprintf` -- they provide `_snprintf` instead -- so if you are careful to use the ANSI function name, you get 80-bit `long double` support automatically).

Comment: Your statement about Microsoft's implementation is incorrect. Microsoft's compiler and runtime *do* implement a `long double` type; it happens to have the same representation as `double` *while still being a distinct type*. Similarly, `short` and `int`, or `int` and `long`, or `long` and `long long` very commonly have the same size, yet they're still distinct types, and nobody says that a compiler doesn't implement `long` if it happens to be the same size as `int`.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler and runtime are consistent and correct; it's the mix of the MS runtime and the gcc compiler that cause this bug in MinGW.

Comment: This is a MinGW bug because it is a bug exhibited by MinGW.  Blaming someone else doesn't change that. The MinGW developers could have chosen not to offload the heavy lifting to other functions that do not do the right job. In fact, they did exactly that for the `printf` version, offering the user the option to get compliant behaviour or MS-forwarding-buggy behaviour.

Comment: So, if you think it is a bug, _file a bug report_; whingeing in a fundamentally irrelevant forum, such as this, achieves nothing.

Comment: @KeithMarshall They are writing a comment telling you that you are wrong and you haven't corrected your answer or addressed them, you just ignored their comment. They may well have filed a bug report, but their comment to tell you they think your first sentence is wrong, is entirely legitimate. Really bugs could perhaps be said to propagate upwards , so it's more accurate to identify it as you have, but I think he has a point in not saying that it's not a mingw bug.