# wrong ans when using long double and correct when using double

Tags: c++

when i declared ans as long double and used "%Lf" in printf, i'm getting always -0.000 as output. But when i declared ans as double and used "%lf" in printf, i'm getting correct ans

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
int main()
{
    ll i,j,k,n,l,a[100000],ma;
    cin>>n>>l;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    ma=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]-a[i-1]>ma)ma=a[i]-a[i-1];
    }
    ll ans1,ans2;
    ans1=a[0];
    ans2=l-a[n-1];
    long double ans=max(ans1,ans2);
    long double rap=ma/2.000;
    if(rap>ans)ans=rap;
    printf("%Lf",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089174/2994596

Comment: The code works for me as long as I change the `printf()` output format according to the output type.

Comment: Which compiler and version and environment are you using

Comment: BTW to actually do the calculation in long double precision, write `ma/2.L;` or `(long double)ma/2`, because `2.000` is a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your last `prinft("%Lf", ans);` function. You specify the format `Lf`, so when you're trying to pass a `double` it fails. Using `cout` instead solves the issue, or simply using `f` as the `printf` format. BTW, your code "fails" for `double`, and "works" for `long double`, not the other way around.

Comment: when i declared ans as long double and used "%Lf" in printf, i'm getting always -0.000. But when i declared ans as double and used "%lf" in printf, i'm getting correct ans

Comment: @rap possibly your implementation doesn't support %Lf which is why I asked in comments on your question