# long double input to scanf

Tags: c, windows, gcc, long-double

I am using windows 10 and MinGW-x64 gcc 8.1.0. I was trying to take a long double as input using scanf. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long double a;
    scanf("%Lf",&a);
    printf("%Lf",a);

    return 0;
}
```

the output on the console is 0.000000.
Why is that so?
Is it a windows issue?

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double. MinGW doesn't support that data type if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Or I think you can use the following `#define printf __mingw_printf` macro to get it "working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess in c mingw does not support long double datatype