# Why an extended precision float-point number is not printed correctly by using Windows x64 assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, sse, x87

The number that I want to print is `real_number_1 dt 1.234567e20`.
The following code is the code I wrote to print, but it finally prints 0.000000e+00.

```
;code

bits 64
default rel

segment .bss
    temp resq 1
segment .data
    real_number_1 dt 1.234567e20 ; extended-precision float
    format_1 db "real_number_1: %le", 0xa, 0
segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern printf



main:

    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32

    fld     TWORD [real_number_1]       ; load 80 bit floating point value to S0 (also push to FPU stack)
    fistp   QWORD [temp]                ; convert ST0 to integer and place in reserved mem location and also pop the FPU stack
    lea     rcx, [format_1]             ; first argument: format string
    cvtsi2sd xmm0, DWORD [temp]         ; convert from integer to double
    movq     rdx, xmm0                  ; move double to 2nd argument loaction
    call    printf

    xor     rax, rax
    call    ExitProcess
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Note: I saw your attempt but code fences use backticks `\`\`\`` and not single quotes `'''`!

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to see what your code is doing and how your to-double conversion really works.

Comment: If I change %le to %lf and I change the code cvtsi2sd xmm0, DWORD [temp] to movq xmm0, QWORD [temp]. The result is real_number_1: -0.000000. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  I tried the debugger but it didn't solve the problem. My aim is to print out the extended double precision number.

Comment: `1.234567e20` is greater than INT64_MAX, so `fistp` produces `0x8000000000000000`. 
 Then you load the low 4 bytes of that (`0`) and convert it to double (`0.0`), and print it.  Looks like you're doing that correctly.  I have no idea why you only read the low dword of the qword integer you stored.  If you wanted to convert to dword, you could have used `fistp` into a dword operand (and gotten the 32-bit "integer indefinite" value, `0x80000000`.  Which as a 2's complement integer represents `-2147483648`)

Comment: Anyway, you're not even trying to print an extended-precision float with printf, just the result of converting it to integer.  (MSVCRT's `printf` probably doesn't have a format for the 80-bit x87 type; MSVC's `long double` is 64-bit, the same format as `double`, IEEE binary64, @Someprogrammerdude.  That's why when the OP printed the 64-bit integer-indefinite bit-pattern  as a `double`, they got negative zero, `-0.000`, because that's what `0x8000000000000000` represents as a `double`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The printf conversion specifier for long double is `%Lf`.  If `%lf` means anything, it means `double`, same as `%f`.  (Default argument promotions to variadic functions mean that `float` isn't an option, unlike with scanf where `%lf` is double and `%f` is float`)  [printf and long double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089174) has an answer that explains how `long double` is not the 80-bit format on Windows unless you use an alternate ABI version of printf, for use with `gcc -mlong-double-80` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html)

Comment: Anyway, what you could do with this huge number is `fstp qword` to convert it to `double`, and pass that to `printf("%e\n", ...`  It's well within the range of DBL_MAX, so its mantissa would just have to get rounded; it wouldn't overflow.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: But they also both mean `double` because in Microsoft land, those are the same type.  So no, the OP's x87 extended precision type does *not* correspond to `long double` in the C library you're talking about, for the same reason that `l` and `L` are the same.  (Or if their documentation explicitly says so?).  See the link in my answer ([printf and long double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089174)) which mentions that MinGW has an alternate libc where `long double` is the 80-bit type.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

`1.234567e20` is greater than `INT64_MAX` (2^63-1), so `fistp` produces 0x8000000000000000, which Intel calls the "integer indefinite" value<sup>1</sup>.  Check with a debugger.

Actually you already did check, according to comments, by passing this 64-bit integer to `printf("%lf"` which interpreted it as a `double` (IEEE binary64) bit-pattern representing negative zero (`-0.00`): just the sign-bit set, rest zero.  That's not in general a useful way to print a 64-bit integer (normally use `%lld` or `%llx`), but in this case essentially confirms the bit pattern.

---

**Then you load the low 4 bytes of that (0) and convert it to double (0.0), and pass it to `printf`**. Looks like you're calling printf correctly.

I have no idea why you only read the low dword of the qword integer you stored. If you wanted to convert to dword, you could have used fistp into a dword operand (and gotten the 32-bit "integer indefinite" value, 0x80000000. Which as a 2's complement integer represents -2147483648, so you'd have ended up with a `double` representing that value.)

Or if you used `cvtsi2sd xmm0, QWORD [temp]`, you'd get `-9223372036854775808.0`.  (The magnitude is a power of 2, specifically 2^63, so `double` can represent it exactly.)

---

Despite your title, your code does *not* even try to print an extended-precision float.  Which is good because you can't with MSVCRT's `printf` on Windows; MSVC doesn't have a format for the 80-bit x87 type since they use `long double` = `double`, so even `printf("%Le"` won't help, unless you use a different `printf`, one designed for use with `gcc -mlong-double-80` where `long double` is the 80-bit type.  (*[printf and long double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double)*)

**One thing you could do with this huge number is `fstp qword` to convert it to `double`**, and pass that (in XMM1 and RDX) to `printf("%e\n", ...`.  It's well within the range of DBL_MAX, so its mantissa would just have to get rounded (to the nearest representable `double`); it wouldn't overflow unless the tbyte value was much larger, with an exponent too larger for a `double`.

Your current code is really weird.  Converting the value to 64-bit integer and back doesn't work for values outside the range of `int64_t`.  And for small values, would round to the nearest integer.  Truncating that `int64_t` to `int32_t` (by using `dword` operand-size when reloading the store in `cvtsi2sd xmm0, DWORD [temp]`) makes even less sense.  I wouldn't describe that as "printing an extended-precision float"!

Unless you're thinking of this as converting to `uint32_t`, in which case yes, converting to `int64_t` and truncating produces correct results for all values that fit in `uint32_t`, unlike if we'd used dword operand-size which would convert to `int32_t`.  In C, it's UB to convert an out-of-range float to integer, so C compilers don't doesn't have to care what result that produces for out-of-range values.

(x86 doesn't have float to unsigned integer conversion until AVX-512.  Fun fact: the integer indefinite value for those is `0xffffffff...`, the max unsigned value for the type.)

Anyway, you're just printing a `double` result of two conversions; things go wrong way before that, as a debugger would show you.

---

**Footnote 1:** https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fist:fistp doesn't give the numeric value of the "integer indefinite" value, presumably that's defined in vol.1 or vol.3 of the SDM.  But the [manual entry for `cvtsd2si`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsd2si) SSE2 double->integer conversion does give the numeric values for 32 and 64-bit operand-size.

Comment: Would you mind sharing why if 1.234567e20 is greater than INT64_MAX (2^63-1), then fistp produces 0x8000000000000000? @Peter Cordes

Comment: @zackjj: Because the manual says so.  See footnote 1 at the bottom of my answer.